# Offer Candidate video not visible to Answer Peer

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, webrtc

I am trying to make a Video Calling app using Flutter, Firebase and Webrtc. I am using the webrtc plugin for flutter from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc.

Say User A can creates the video call and User B joins the call then User B (who answered the call) can see the video of the first user (User A). But User A who created the offer cannot see User B's video. Audio on both the sides are working OKAY. Testing on Real Devices.

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_final_fields

import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

import '../../constants.dart';
import '../../widgets/fs_text.dart';

typedef StreamStateCallback = void Function(MediaStream stream);

class CallScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> args;
  static const routeName = '/callScreen';
  const CallScreen({super.key, required this.args});

  @override
  State<CallScreen> createState() => _CallScreenState();
}

class _CallScreenState extends State<CallScreen> {
  // Signaling signaling = Signaling();
  RTCVideoRenderer _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  RTCVideoRenderer _remoteRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  MediaStream? localStream;
  MediaStream? remoteStream;
  RTCPeerConnection? peerConnection;
  String? roomId;
  StreamStateCallback? onAddRemoteStream;
  StreamStateCallback? onRemoveRemoteStream;
  bool isMicMute = false;
  bool isVideoEnabled = false;
  bool isSpeakerOn = false;

  static const Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
    "sdpSemantics": "plan-b",
    'iceServers': [
      {
        'urls': [
          'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
          'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  static const Map<String, dynamic> offerSdpConstraints = {
    "mandatory": {
      "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
      "OfferToReceiveVideo": true,
    },
    "optional": [],
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    _localRenderer.initialize();
    _remoteRenderer.initialize();

    onAddRemoteStream = ((stream) {
      _remoteRenderer.srcObject = stream;
      setState(() {});
    });
    // onRemoveRemoteStream = ((stream) {
    //   _localRenderer.dispose();
    //   _remoteRenderer.dispose();
    //   setState(() {});
    // });

    openUserMedia(_localRenderer, _remoteRenderer)
        .then((value) => setState(() {}));
    if (!widget.args.containsKey("roomId")) {
      createRoom().then((value) => setState(() => roomId = value));
    } else {
      openUserMedia(_localRenderer, _remoteRenderer)
          .then((value) => setState(() {}));
      joinRoom(widget.args["roomId"]).then((value) => setState(() {}));
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  createRoom() async {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    DocumentReference roomRef = db.collection('rooms').doc();
    peerConnection =
        await createPeerConnection(configuration, offerSdpConstraints);
    setState(() {});

    registerPeerConnectionListeners(context);

    localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) {
      peerConnection?.addTrack(track, localStream!);
    });

    // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
    var callerCandidatesCollection = roomRef.collection('offerCandidate');

    peerConnection?.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
      callerCandidatesCollection.add(candidate.toMap());
    };
    // Finish Code for collecting ICE candidate

    // Add code for creating a room
    RTCSessionDescription offer = await peerConnection!.createOffer();
    await peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(_fixSdp(offer));

    Map<String, dynamic> roomWithOffer = {
      'offer': offer.toMap(),
      "roomId": roomRef.id
    };
    roomWithOffer.addAll(widget.args);

    await roomRef.set(roomWithOffer);
    var roomId = roomRef.id;
    //  currentRoomText = 'Current room is $roomId - You are the caller!';
    // Created a Room

    peerConnection?.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
      print(event.streams.length);
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) {
        remoteStream?.addTrack(track);
      });
    };
    peerConnection?.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) {
      onAddRemoteStream?.call(stream);
      remoteStream = stream;
    };
    await peerConnection?.addStream(localStream!);

    // Listening for remote session description below
    roomRef.snapshots().listen((snapshot) async {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (data["status"] == "rejected") {
        hangUp(_localRenderer).then((value) {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
              ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
                  content: FsText(
                      "${data["userName"]} ${data["status"]} your call",
                      size: 14,
                      color: Colors.white),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red));
          });
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });
        return;
      }

      if (data['answer'] != null) {
        var answer = RTCSessionDescription(
          data['answer']['sdp'],
          data['answer']['type'],
        );

        await peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(answer);
      }
    });
    // Listening for remote session description above

    // Listen for remote Ice candidates below
    roomRef.collection('answerCandidate').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      for (var change in snapshot.docChanges) {
        //  if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = change.doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        peerConnection!.addCandidate(
          RTCIceCandidate(
            data['candidate'],
            data['sdpMid'],
            data['sdpMLineIndex'],
          ),
        );
        // }
      }
    });
    return roomId;
  }

  RTCSessionDescription _fixSdp(RTCSessionDescription s) {
    var sdp = s.sdp;
    s.sdp =
        sdp!.replaceAll('profile-level-id=640c1f', 'profile-level-id=42e032');
    return s;
  }

  Future joinRoom(String joinRoomId) async {
    roomId = joinRoomId;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    DocumentReference roomRef = db.collection('rooms').doc(joinRoomId);
    var roomSnapshot = await roomRef.get();

    if (roomSnapshot.exists) {
      peerConnection =
          await createPeerConnection(configuration, offerSdpConstraints);
      setState(() {});
      registerPeerConnectionListeners(context);
      localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) {
        peerConnection?.addTrack(track, localStream!);
      });

      // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
      var calleeCandidatesCollection = roomRef.collection('answerCandidate');
      peerConnection!.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
        // if (candidate == null) {
        //   print('onIceCandidate: complete!');
        //   return;
        // }
        calleeCandidatesCollection.add(candidate.toMap());
      };
      // Code for collecting ICE candidate above

      peerConnection?.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
        print(event.streams.length);
        event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) {
          remoteStream?.addTrack(track);
        });
      };
      peerConnection?.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) {
        onAddRemoteStream?.call(stream);
        remoteStream = stream;
      };
      await peerConnection?.addStream(localStream!);
      // Code for creating SDP answer below
      var data = roomSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var offer = data['offer'];
      await peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(
        RTCSessionDescription(offer['sdp'], offer['type']),
      );
      var answer = await peerConnection!.createAnswer();

      await peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(_fixSdp(answer));

      Map<String, dynamic> roomWithAnswer = {
        'answer': {'type': answer.type, 'sdp': answer.sdp}
      };
      roomWithAnswer.addAll(widget.args);

      await roomRef.update(roomWithAnswer);
      // Finished creating SDP answer
      // String userName = "";
      // Listening for remote ICE candidates below
      // roomRef.snapshots().listen((snapshot) async {
      //   print('Got updated room: ${snapshot.data()}');

      //   if (snapshot.data() == null) {
      //     // hangUp(localRenderer).then((value) {
      //     //   showSnack(context: context, message: "$userName ended the call");
      //     //   return;
      //     // });
      //     // Navigator.of(context).pop();
      //     return;
      //   }
      //   Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      //   userName = data["userName"];
      // });
      roomRef.collection('offerCandidate').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
        for (var document in snapshot.docChanges) {
          var data = document.doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          peerConnection!.addCandidate(
            RTCIceCandidate(
              data['candidate'],
              data['sdpMid'],
              data['sdpMLineIndex'],
            ),
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    peerConnection?.dispose();
    peerConnection?.close();
    localStream?.dispose();
    remoteStream?.dispose();

    _localRenderer.dispose();
    _remoteRenderer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    peerConnection?.dispose();
    peerConnection?.close();
    localStream?.dispose();
    remoteStream?.dispose();

    _localRenderer.dispose();
    _remoteRenderer.dispose();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant CallScreen oldWidget) {
    setState(() {});
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log(_remoteRenderer.srcObject?.getTracks().join(" _ ") ?? "null");
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("rooms")
            .doc(roomId)
            .update({"status": "ended", "endTime": DateTime.now()});
        hangUp(_localRenderer);
        if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: const Text("Welcome to Flutter Explained - WebRTC"),
        // ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [greyColor, primaryColor]),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: (_remoteRenderer.srcObject?.getTracks() ?? []).isEmpty
                    ? Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border:
                                    Border.all(color: primaryColor, width: 2),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 78,
                              backgroundImage: widget
                                      .args["friendImage"].isEmpty
                                  ? null
                                  : NetworkImage(widget.args["friendImage"]),
                              child: widget.args["friendImage"].isEmpty
                                  ? const Icon(CupertinoIcons.person, size: 18)
                                  : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          FsText(
                            widget.args["userName"],
                            //  color: secondaryColor,
                            size: 30,
                            weight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 6),
                          const FsText(
                            "Ringing...",
                            //  color: secondaryColor,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            weight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 40),
                        ],
                      )
                    : RTCVideoView(
                        _remoteRenderer,
                        objectFit:
                            RTCVideoViewObjectFit.RTCVideoViewObjectFitCover,
                      ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  right: 20,
                  top: 40,
                  child: Container(
                      height: 160,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: primaryColor),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          child: RTCVideoView(
                            _localRenderer,
                            mirror: true,
                            objectFit: RTCVideoViewObjectFit
                                .RTCVideoViewObjectFitCover,
                          )))),
              Positioned(
                  bottom: 20,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .05,
                  //top: 40,
                  child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 80,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                          color: greyColor),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              switchSpeakerPhone(isSpeakerOn);
                              setState(() {
                                isSpeakerOn = !isSpeakerOn;
                              });
                            },
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor:
                                    isSpeakerOn ? Colors.white : null,
                                maxRadius: 26,
                                minRadius: 16,
                                child: Icon(
                                  CupertinoIcons.speaker_2,
                                  size: 22,
                                  color:
                                      isSpeakerOn ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
                                )),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              showHideCamera();
                              setState(() {
                                isVideoEnabled = !isVideoEnabled;
                              });
                            },
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                maxRadius: 26,
                                minRadius: 16,
                                backgroundColor:
                                    isVideoEnabled ? null : Colors.white,
                                child: Icon(
                                  CupertinoIcons.video_camera,
                                  size: 22,
                                  color: isVideoEnabled
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : primaryColor,
                                )),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                muteMic();
                                setState(() {
                                  isMicMute = !isMicMute;
                                });
                              },
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                  maxRadius: 26,
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      isMicMute ? Colors.white : null,
                                  minRadius: 16,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CupertinoIcons.mic,
                                    size: 22,
                                    color:
                                        isMicMute ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
                                  ))),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                switchCamera();
                              },
                              child: const CircleAvatar(
                                  maxRadius: 26,
                                  minRadius: 16,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CupertinoIcons.switch_camera,
                                    size: 22,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ))),
                        ],
                      ))),
              Positioned(
                  left: 20,
                  top: 40,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("rooms")
                          .doc(roomId)
                          .update(
                              {"status": "ended", "endTime": DateTime.now()});
                      hangUp(_localRenderer);
                      if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
                    },
                    child: const CircleAvatar(
                        maxRadius: 26,
                        minRadius: 16,
                        backgroundColor: redColor,
                        child: Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.phone_down,
                          size: 22,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void registerPeerConnectionListeners(BuildContext context) {
    peerConnection?.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {};

    peerConnection?.onConnectionState = (RTCPeerConnectionState state) {
      if (state == RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateDisconnected ||
          state == RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateClosed) {
        localStream?.dispose();
        if (remoteStream != null) {
          remoteStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
        }
        if (peerConnection != null) peerConnection!.close();
        remoteStream?.dispose();
        _remoteRenderer.srcObject?.dispose();
        _remoteRenderer.dispose();
        peerConnection?.close();
        peerConnection?.dispose();
        if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      }
    };

    peerConnection?.onSignalingState = (RTCSignalingState state) {
      if (state == RTCSignalingState.RTCSignalingStateClosed) {
        localStream?.dispose();
        if (remoteStream != null) {
          remoteStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
        }
        if (peerConnection != null) peerConnection!.close();
        remoteStream?.dispose();
        _remoteRenderer.dispose();
        peerConnection?.close();
        peerConnection?.dispose();

        if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      }
    };

    peerConnection?.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {};
    peerConnection?.onRemoveStream = (stream) async {
      peerConnection?.removeStream(stream);
      remoteStream = null;
      _remoteRenderer.srcObject = null;
      setState(() {});
    };
    peerConnection?.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) async {
      log("remote stream added " + stream.getTracks().join(" _ "));
      await peerConnection?.addStream(stream);
      remoteStream = stream;
      _remoteRenderer.srcObject = remoteStream;
      setState(() {});
    };
  }

  void switchCamera() {
    if (localStream != null) {
      Helper.switchCamera(localStream!.getVideoTracks()[0]);
    }
  }

  void switchSpeakerPhone(bool setOn) {
    if (localStream != null) {
      Helper.setSpeakerphoneOn(setOn);
    }
  }

  void showHideCamera() {
    if (localStream != null) {
      bool enabled = localStream!.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
      localStream!.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !enabled;
    }
  }

  void muteMic() {
    if (localStream != null) {
      bool enabled = localStream!.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
      localStream!.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = !enabled;
    }
  }

  Future<void> openUserMedia(
    RTCVideoRenderer localVideo,
    RTCVideoRenderer remoteVideo,
  ) async {
    var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      'video': {
        'mandatory': {
          'minWidth': '640',
          'minHeight': '480',
          'minFrameRate': '30',
        },
        'facingMode': 'user',
        'optional': [],
      },
      'audio': true
    });

    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;

    //remoteVideo.srcObject = await createLocalMediaStream('key');
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> hangUp(RTCVideoRenderer localVideo) async {
    List<MediaStreamTrack> tracks = localVideo.srcObject!.getTracks();
    for (var track in tracks) {
      track.stop();
    }

    if (remoteStream != null) {
      remoteStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
    // if (peerConnection != null) peerConnection!.close();

    localStream!.dispose();
    remoteStream?.dispose();

    peerConnection?.close();
    peerConnection?.dispose();
    // if (roomId != null) {
    //   var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    //   var roomRef = db.collection('rooms').doc(roomId);
    //   var calleeCandidates = await roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates').get();
    //   for (var document in calleeCandidates.docs) {
    //     document.reference.delete();
    //   }

    //   var callerCandidates = await roomRef.collection('callerCandidates').get();
    //   for (var document in callerCandidates.docs) {
    //     document.reference.delete();
    //   }

    //   await roomRef.delete();
    // }
  }
}
```

Here is the full code of the problem I am facing. Please let me know if you can find any fix.

Comment: There are 660 lines of code in your question. While someone my of course happen to find the time to read all that, spot the problem, and provide an answer, chances of that drastically go up if you take the time to create an isolated reproduction of the problem from scratch. Follow the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase the chances that someone can help.